# Use of 'who' in Indian English

Tags: subcontinental-english, who

In both statements, which person is the word 'who' used for?

> 1. Maya is sister of dhara who is doctor.

> 2. Maya is sister of dhara, who is doctor.

Comment: In UK, Canadian and US English the wording is wrong. It would have to be "Maya is **the** sister of Dhara, who is **a** doctor". This appears to be common enough in Indian English that it may be considered acceptable: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/57807/omission-of-definite-article-in-indian-english

Comment: The tag here is `indian-english`. I know nothing about that usage, so I'm unable to answer with any authority. (Otherwise, I'd say that both sentences are ungrammatical.) In the version without a comma, *who* specifically modifies *Dhara*. In the version with a comma, it's ambiguous—but, everything being equal, the assumption is that it modifies the closest noun: Dhara.

Comment: Honestly, even after growing up hearing Indian English, I can't tell. I personally feel as though the comma would make little difference and Dhara would be the doctor in both cases if someone said this to me in Indian English, but I have no logical reasoning to back it up.

Answer (score 3):

The relative pronoun, *who*, should refer directly to the antecedent.  Note the position of the commas.

> 1. Maya, **who** is the sister of Dhara, is a doctor.
>      *Maya [who has a sister called Dhara] is a doctor*
> 2. Maya is the sister of Dhara **who** is a doctor
>      *Maya has a sister (Dhara) who is a doctor*

Answer (score 0):

It is worth bearing in mind what Sidney Greenbaum says of the comma in his *Oxford English Grammar* 11.18

> Commas are by far the most frequently occurring punctuation marks within sentences.  They are the lightest of the marks and the most versatile, used to separate units and in a variety of contexts to isolate units.  They are also the most flexible of marks, since writers often have the choice whether or not to insert them. Commas offer scope for assisting readers to understand the text. Writers show their skill in punctuation  by their judicious use of commas: too many commas slow down reading and can obstruct comprehension; too few can promote ambiguity.

This summary makes it clear that the main purposes of commas is clarity and ease of reading.  It brings a short pause.

The sentence at issue is too short, therefore, for it to matter one way or the other.  It is obvious what is meant either way.

If we suppose that there are two Dharas in the room, one a doctor and one a librarian.  Amid confusing introductions, a newly arriving guest asks "which Dhara is Maya related to?".  Then the comma should be omitted.

> Maya is the sister of the Dhara who is a doctor.

In the O.P. question, there is no article so that we are getting two statements, one answering the unstated question 'who is Maya?', the other answering the implied question 'which Dhaya?'.

In my experience as an inspector of schools in England, most teachers at schools in the UK would expect a comma after 'Dhaya' in the sentence and so would markers of examination papers. But punctuation is not a grammatical phenomenon. As Greenbaum puts it [OEG 11.1]:

> One set of writing systems in English bears some relationship to systems in the spoken language: the conventions for spelling .... correspond in some measure to the sounds used in speech. On the other hand, the conventions of punctuation ... reflect only crudely -if at all- the pauses and intonational patterns that occur in speech.

Answer (score -3):

Maya is the sister of Dhara who is a doctor. --> Maya is a doctor here.
Maya is a sister of Dhara, who is a doctor. --> Dhara is a doctor in this case.